# Symmetric encryption in BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle

```
KeyParameter param = new KeyParameter(password);

cipher.Init(true, param);
PaddedBufferedBlockCipher blockCipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(cipher, new ZeroBytePadding());
```

This is how I set up my cipher in BouncyCastle. How come there is no IV to choose or block mode? How does it work?

Comment: A password is not a key and should not directly be used as such. Please lookup PBKDF's such as PBKDF2 or Argon2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few things to know about Bouncy Castle. Compared to the Java JCE or .NET classes there are multiple layers to each full cipher:

1. the block cipher;
2. the mode;
3. the buffering and padding.

Furthermore, there is a base `CipherParameters` class that contains instances that are accepted by all these classes. It is type-checked within the different cipher classes and if information is required then it is extracted, otherwise it is generally just handed to the parent.

---

OK, so that may all be a bit abstract, so I've created an example where first a block cipher instance is created, then that is used to generate a mode of operation and finally a buffered instance that also performs the padding.

I've deliberately used the interface type for the variables so you can see the inheritance structure.

Oh yeah, and I've used Java, but the general structure is of course the same across the Java and C# API.

```java
package se.so;

import org.bouncycastle.crypto.BlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.CipherParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.AESEngine;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.CBCBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.ZeroBytePadding;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ParametersWithIV;

public class PaddedBufferedBC {

    private static final boolean FOR_ENCRYPTION = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        byte[] keyData = new byte[16];
        CipherParameters key = new KeyParameter(keyData);

        byte[] ivData = new byte[16];
        CipherParameters keyAndIV = new ParametersWithIV(key, ivData);

        // absorbs the key
        BlockCipher blockCipher = new AESEngine();
        // absorbs the IV (missing in the code of the question)
        BlockCipher cbcBlockCipher = new CBCBlockCipher(blockCipher);
        // simply passes on the key and IV
        PaddedBufferedBlockCipher bufferedBlockCipher =
                new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(cbcBlockCipher, new ZeroBytePadding());
        // initialization should be on the last wrapper class
        bufferedBlockCipher.init(FOR_ENCRYPTION, keyAndIV);

        // just to test that I didn't make any mistakes
        System.out.println(bufferedBlockCipher.getUpdateOutputSize(100));
    }

}
```

---

Note that stream ciphers or ciphers in streaming mode (e.g. counter mode, `SICBlockCipher`) may not need to be wrapped with a `PaddedBufferedBlockCipher`.

Comment: Feel free to port the code to C# and edit this answer so it can contain actual C# code, with a `const` instead of a `static final` and `Init` and such.

Comment: Does this answer work for you at all or is anything missing? Is there any problem converting this to C#? I'd hate to setup my .NET environment (again) as my personal laptop broke down.

Comment: No, everything is ok. Thanks for your answer, it helped me a lot.I was also wondering, should I use CipherParameters with IV even if I have used some password derivator earlier?

Comment: The most common way is to split the output of the password derivation into a key and IV. But as long as the derived key is unique (e.g. because of a random salt) then you could do without an IV (or an all zero IV). I prefer the derived IV. Whatever you do, not not reuse a key/IV combination; use a random IV and include it with the ciphertext if you're not sure!

Comment: By the way, you may take a look at e.g. the authenticated GCM mode. In general Bouncy Castle is software only; using platform native calls may be faster and possibly more secure, e.g. because of AES-NI support on Intel/AMD Ryzen CPU's

Comment: Yes, I want to use GCM mode. It is supposed to be more secure if implemented correctly.